# How to refers to single characters of a word

Tags: positioning, xstring

I need to positionate every single digit of a number in some positions, (i.e. 1234,35 euros) in single cells of a module.
How  I can refer to single digit?
Thank you.

I wish to do something like this :

[image]

Comment: Can you give us an example that shows what you are trying to do, and what does not work?  I'm struggling to make sense of what you mean by "in the same positions" and "in single cells of a module".

Comment: I think you mean 'access' the digit, not 'referring'

Comment: Excuse me, my fault. "in s**O**me positions".
I want to compile a prestamped module, with cells for digits, like this:
http://www.bollettinoonline.it/static/bollettino/img/esempio.gif